# Create join model record with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have following models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :project_users, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :projects, through: :project_users
end

class ProjectUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :project
   has_many :participants
   has_many :tasks, through: :participants
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :project
   has_many :participants
   has_many :project_users, through: :participants
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :participants
end

class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :project_user
   belongs_to :task
 end
```

So the flow should go like this:
1. User creates the project
2. User adds users to project via the join model ProjectUser
3. User creates a task for the project and selects those users from ProjectUsers, who will participate in the task. So I put an accepts_nested_attributes_for method and tried to build the nested form.

**In my controller:**

```
 def new
    @task = Task.new
    @task.participants.build
 end

 def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:project_id, :project_phase_id, :priority_id, :title,     :due_date, :estimation, :responsible_id, :description, :participant_ids => [])#, :participants_attributes => [:project_user_id, :task_id])
 end
```

participants_attributes is commented

**In my view:**

```
= f.association :participants, as: :select
```

**Actual HTML generated:**

```
 <input name="task[participant_ids][]" type="hidden" value="">
 <select class="select optional form-control" id="task_participant_ids" multiple="multiple" name="task[participant_ids][]">
   <option value="57">AlexandeR MazeiN</option>
   <option value="59">Firenze</option>
   <option value="58">Vasily Strekotkin</option>
 </select>
```

I add options via ajax, value = ProjectUser.id
I Have to do it like so, because I dont know which ProjectUsers there will be unless a concrete project for a task is selected.

**Error I am getting:**

```
Started POST "/tasks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-11 13:18:24 +0300
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 6 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aXuk9ZuDvFZce+sbIQLRhWZlVjitMvySaJ7CwWfdmaQ=", "task"=>{"project_id"=>"20", "priority_id"=>"4", "project_phase_id"=>"40", "title"=>"Skepta", "due_date"=>"", "estimation"=>"8", "responsible_id"=>"6", "participant_ids"=>["", "57", "58"], "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Task"}
  Team Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Participant Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "participants".* FROM "participants" WHERE "participants"."id" IN (57, 58)
Completed 404 Not Found in 7ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find all Participants with IDs (57, 58) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2):
```

Comment: Please add error backtrace.

Comment: What are 57, 58 & 59 the ids of?  Ie which class?

Comment: 57, 58, 59 are the ids of Projectuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `param` hash has the IDs from `ProjectUser` as `participant_ids`, so when it queries the database it is looking for `Participant` models with these IDs. You need to set these as `project_user_id` inside of a list of participants, something like this:

```
participants: [ { project_user_id: 57 }, { project_user_id: 58 } ]
```

I'm not super familiar with `build`, but something along these lines should allow AR to properly construct the associations.